# When will elements in storyboard be created?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, storyboard, xctest

I am using XCTest to test my view controller.

I have to validate my `textfield`, so I initialized a view controller from my storyboard and tried to access the `textfiled`:

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
ViewController *vc = (ViewController *)[sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
XCTAssertNotNil(_vc.emailField, @"email field is nil!"); // fail
```

I can access `emailField` and set/get value for it if I use simulator to test this view controller manually, but I can not access it through my code(`_vc.emailField` is nil).

I want to know:

1. from the perspective of code, when will the elements in storyboard be created by iOS. (I guessed they would be created in `viewDidLoad`, but I found I was wrong after testing it)
2. how can I access the elements in XCTest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the view elements in the `xib` will be available after the view is loaded. The issue is that you are never actually causing the view to be loaded.

You should call `viewController.view`, which will cause the view to be loaded and all of the outlets to be connected up.

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
ViewController *vc = (ViewController *)[sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];

__unused UIView *view = _vc.view; // cause the view to be loaded

XCTAssertNotNil(_vc.emailField, @"email field is nil!");
```

Answer (score 0):

The properties should be created in `viewDidLoad`, but setting the actual text properties cannot be done until `viewWillAppear:`

The way I fix this problem is to add another property to the view controller to contain the data (as a view should not be the primary owner of any stored data anyway) and set the value of `vc.emailField.text` to that property in `viewWillAppear`